# creating list<datetime> in flutterflow

Tags: flutterflow

How can we store list in Flutterflow? I am getting trouble as I am trying to store multiple datetime values in list which suppose to store on different indexes.
I tried create document and update document method but both did not workout update workout somehow but i have to give different datetime everytime to store values in list otherwise same values get replaced with each other

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.